# Java ArrayList in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

When I submit the form to server, Rails.logger.info params
gives

```
{"cgAttr"=>{"1"=>"abc,pqr", "2"=>"US"}}
```

and I want

```
{"cgAttr"=>{"1"=>"abc", "1" => "pqr", "2"=>"US"}}
```

PS. "1" is input text box in UI that take multiple comma-separate values ("abc,pqr") and on server I am converting that entire string into array (["abc", "pqr"]).

Can Any one point me in correct direction?

Basically, I want to create ArrayList similar to Java in my Ruby on Rails application. Does anyone know how to achieve it. (I have not tried JRuby plugin yet)

Comment: JRuby is not a "plugin", it is a complete implementation of the Ruby language.

Comment: Ruby hash indexes MUST be unique. You are asking for the hash to have two "1" indexes, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer is to use `split`:

```
arr = params[:cgAttr]["1"].split(",")
```

(Also not psyched about using "1" as a parameter name.)

Comment: if I do that than it gives "1"=>["abc", "pqr"]. Is there a way I can achieve  {"cgAttr"=>{"1"=>"abc", "1" => "pqr", "2"=>"US"}}

Comment: @Viral No, it's a hash. It's not really clear what you're actually trying to do; are you sending something *to* a Java server? You could use array notation and say { "foo[0]" => "abc", "foo[1]" => "pqr" }. Otherwise you're going to need to be more specific. My code snippet is on the rails side and cannot produce what you're saying, because I'm *consuming* parameters.

Comment: yeah dave, thanks for guidance..I am actually send values to Java API but the API accept values in this cgAttr = [{name: "abc", loc: "us"}, {name:"pqr", loc:"us"}]. Do you think creating my own hash map will help me?

Comment: @Viral That's a completely different structure; that's an array of hashes. Sure, creating that from the form data would be trivial.

Comment: ok got it...I was trying to explore more options to match that data structure...not sure if I use JRuby that will help me or not.

Comment: @Viral No; JRuby is just Ruby. If you're making a structure to pass via HTTP/etc. the Ruby side will use Ruby semantics, regardless of which implementation is used.

Comment: @dave..yeah read their dopcumentation...However, I found interesting article on [google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=ows9jTsyaaEC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=ruby+data+structure+to+allow+%22duplicate+keys%22&source=bl&ots=imLDFQrgCi&sig=kEYIcd7NOxx_VX00ka9R9IO8Df0&hl=en&ei=BnvVTvWFLdDciAKd4pWNDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ruby%20data%20structure%20to%20allow%20%22duplicate%20keys%22&f=false) to have duplicate values in Hash (not exactly hash)

Comment: @Viral Not sure what the JSON output of that would be. Why not just do it right?

Comment: @Viral It'd go a lot quicker on SO if you were specific w/ what you were doing, how, and what you need.

Comment: @dave, yeah sorry will make sure next time...be very specific..thanks for your input and time.  I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, hash key must be a unique value:

```
{:foo => 'foo1', :foo => 'foo2'} #=> {:foo => 'foo2'}
```

Think about it, how would you differentiate between the two elements?  `my_hash[:foo]` can only refer to one element, but if two elements have the same :foo key how can you distinguish between the two?

I like Dave Newtons answer, because then you can actually access them, e.g.:

```
my_hash[:foo][0], my_hash[:foo][1]
```

Comment: yeah that make more sense...will check any other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

It can be done:

```
h = {}
h.compare_by_identity
a = "1"
b = "1"
h[a] = "abc"
h[b] = "pqr"
p h # {"1"=>"abc", "1"=>"pqr"}
```

but it doesn't feel right.